# QIntValidator error in Qt

Tags: qt, validation

I have written the following part of a code that adds two numbers together and outputs the result:

```
QIntValidator *validator = new QIntValidator(0,50,this);
ui->firstNumber->setValidator(validator);
...
...
```

In this case, I get the following error:

```
CS2039:  'setValidator': is not a member of QTextEditor
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Use a text input class that supports validation.  You probably want `QLineEdit`